# SQL Server - count how many names have 'A' and how many have 'E'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with SQL query.

I have names in column `Name` in `Table_Name`, for example:

```
'Mila', 'Adrianna' 'Emma', 'Edward', 'Adam', 'Piter'
```

I would like to count how many names contain the letter `'A'` and how many contain the letter `'E'`.

The output should be:

```
letter_A ( 5 )| letter_E (3)
```

I tried to do this:

```
SELECT Name,
       letter_A = CHARINDEX('A', Name),
       letter_E = CHARINDEX('E', Name)
FROM   Table_Name
GROUP  BY Name
HAVING ( CHARINDEX('A', Nazwisko) != 0
          OR ( CHARINDEX('E', Nazwisko) ) != 0 )
```

My query only shows if 'A' or 'E' is in Name :/

Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to aggregate if you only need the counts.

```
select 
 sum(case when charindex('a',name) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as a_count
,sum(case when charindex('e',name) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as e_count
from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when Nazwisko like '%A%' then 1 else 0 end) as A_cnt,
       sum(case when Nazwisko like '%E%' then 1 else 0 end) as E_cnt       
from table_name
where Nazwisko like '%A%' or Nazwisko like '%E%';
```

Comment: Technically that `WHERE` clause isn't required unless you want to have a `COUNT(*) AS either_cnt` to determine how much the `A_cnt` and `E_cnt` overlap.

Comment: Thanks this is what i need :)

Comment: @Mr.Llama It allows non matching values to be eliminated in the scan without passing them out and counting them. - albeit at the expense of processing the string twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT NAME
         FROM   (VALUES ('MILA'),
                        ('ADRIANNA'),
                        ('EMMA'),
                        ('EDWARD'),
                        ('ADAM'),
                        ('PITER'))V(NAME)),
     CTE_NAME
     AS (SELECT COUNT(NAME_A) NAME_A,
                COUNT(NAME_E) NAME_E
         FROM  (SELECT CASE
                         WHEN NAME LIKE '%A%' THEN NAME
                       END NAME_A,
                       CASE
                         WHEN NAME LIKE '%E%' THEN NAME
                       END NAME_E
                FROM   CTE
                GROUP  BY NAME)A)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE_NAME
```